# Unable to run multiple threads inside a cucumber step definition

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, threadpoolexecutor, cucumber-java

I want to fetch db data in parallel using threadpoolexecutor but for some reason using cucumber feature and step definition file to run this code. Project structure look like this:

feature file::

```
    Given Get total count of account number
```

Step Definition::

```
@Given("Get total count of account number")
    public void getTotalCountOfAccountNumber() {
int totalBatches = 0;
        int lowRange = 1;
        int highRange = batchSize;
        totalBatches = calculateTotalBatches();
        System.out.println(totalBatches);
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max_threads);

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalBatches; i++) {
            Runnable r = new FetchACCNumberFromDBTask(lowRange,highRange,i);
            executor.execute(r);
            lowRange = highRange+1;
            highRange += batchSize;
        }
        executor.shutdown();
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. There is no exception, just program runs and completes without any error. If I put the step definition into a main method and run, it works fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting an exception, please [edit] your question to include the message and stack trace.

Comment: No there is no exception, just program runs and completes without any error

Comment: I edited your question to include this information. This avoids the down-votes from people looking for this information. The fact no exception is thrown could be critical to identifying a fix.